# Differential Equation that do not contain "y" directly.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential

I've been on this question for two days and I can't seem to get past the last integral. The natural logarithm of y seems to be a problem $\mathrm{ y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{dy}{dx} + \Bigl(\frac{dy}{dx}\Bigl)^3} = 0\\
\mathrm {substiting \,  dy/dx = p,  \,  d²y/dx² = pdp/dy}\\
\mathrm{ reduces \, the \, equation\,  to} \\
\mathrm{ yp\frac{dp}{dy} + p +p^3= 0} \implies \mathrm{y\frac{dp}{dy} + 1 +p^2= 0}\\
\mathrm{\frac{dp}{1+p^2} + \frac{dy}{y}}= 0 \implies  \mathrm{ tan^{-1}p + Iny = C}\\
\mathrm{p = tan{(c - Iny) }} \implies\mathrm{\frac{dy}{tan(c-Iny)} = dx}$\.

Is there another method to go about it?

Comment: Wolfram performs the same method as you have. The final integral is non-elementary.

Comment: Thanks peter foreman.. I thought same too but the textbook gave the answer as $\mathrm{y = a - sin^{-1}(be^{-x}} $ which made me confused. Thanks